# Efficient algorithm to fit a linear line along the upper boundary of data only

Tags: algorithm, matlab, curve-fitting

I'm currently trying to fit a linear line through a spread of scattered data in MATLAB. Now this is easy enough using the polyfit function where I can easily obtain my y= mx + c equation. However, I need to now fit a line along the upper boundary of my data, i.e., the top few data points. I know this description is vague, so lets assume that my scattered data will be in a shape of a cone, with its apex on the y-axis, and it spreads outwards and upwards in the +x and +y direction. I need to fit a best fit line on the 'upper edge of the cone' if you will.

I've developed an algorithm but it's extremely slow. It involves first fitting a line of best fit through ALL data, deleting all data points below this line of best fit, and iterating through until only 5% of the initial data points are left. The final best fit line will then reside close to the top edge of the cone. For 250 data points, this takes about 5s and with me dealing with more than a million data points, this algorithm is simply too inefficient.

I guess my question is: is there an algorithm to more efficiently achieve what I need? Or is there a way to sharpen up my code to eliminate unnecessary complexity?

Here is my code in MATLAB:

(As an example)

```
a = [4, 5, 1, 8, 1.6, 3, 8, 9.2]; %To be used as x-axis points
b = [45, 53, 12, 76, 25, 67, 75, 98]; %To be used as y-axis points

while prod(size(a)) > (0.05*prod(size(a))) %Iterative line fitting occurs until there are less than 5% of the data points left

      lobf = polyfit(a,b,1); %Line of Best Fit for current data points

      alen = length(a);

      for aindex = alen:-1:1 %For loop to delete all points below line of best fit

            ValLoBF = lobf(1)*a(aindex) + lobf(2)

            if ValLoBF > b(aindex) %if LoBF is above current point...
                   a(aindex) = []; %delete x coordinate...
                   b(aindex) = []; %and delete its corresponding y coordinate
            end
      end

end
```

Comment: Could you please upload a drawing of what kind of line you would like to fit? I couldn't understand from the description.

Comment: Hah I already have a drawing because I wanted to make it clearer. I can't upload pictures because I have no rep though >_<

Comment: How about after doing the first fit, you "rotate" all the points towards zero and then remove whatever is below zero (or some positive value which you decide) and rotate them back? This way you may be able to get rid of much of the data easily.

p.s.
You can upload an image to an external site and put a link.

Comment: How would that be different from simply eliminating points below the line? Wouldn't even need the 2 rotations that way

Comment: Because I think you could avoid the loops altogether... And only do a couple of fits. || BTW, when you profile this code, where is the majority of computation time spent?

Comment: Found a good image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F2lRp.png

Lets say I want to fit a line on the upper left edge of the triangle in this case. In general, the algorithm would fit a line through the "top most edge" of the scattered data, whatever its shape.

Comment: Time is spent significantly in the for loop where I delete all points below the line of best fit

Comment: Can you upload the code that generates the point? I know how to solve your problem

Comment: are actually looking for a [Pareto Frontier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_frontier#Use_in_engineering)?

Comment: In a sense, yes! I want to fit a line of best fit for the (upper boundary) Pareto frontier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all your example code seems to be running indefinitely ;)

Some optimizations for your code:

```
a = [4, 5, 1, 8, 1.6, 3, 8, 9.2]; %To be used as x-axis points
b = [45, 53, 12, 76, 25, 67, 75, 98]; %To be used as y-axis points

n_init_a = length(a);

while length(a) > 0.05*n_init_a %Iterative line fitting occurs until there are less     than 5% of the data points left

  lobf = polyfit(a,b,1); % Line of Best Fit for current data points

  % Delete data points below line using logical indexing
  % First create values of the polyfit points using element-wise vector multiplication
  temp = lobf(1)*a + lobf(2); % Containing all polyfit values
  % Using logical indexing to discard all points below
  a(b<temp)=[]; % First destroy a
  b(b<temp)=[]; % Then b, very important!

end
```

Also you should try profiling your code by typing in the command window

```
profile viewer
```

and check what takes most time calculating your results. I suspect it is polyfit but that can't be sped up much probably.

Comment: This actually worked! Gajillion times faster! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to check your output visually to see if the fit is acceptable to you! Also try to avoid for loops when there is no need for them in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not line fitting. You are trying to find the convex hull of the points.
[image]

You should check out the function `convhull`. Once you find the hull, you can remove all of the points that aren't close to it, and fit each part independently to avoid the fact that the data is noisy.

---

Alternatively, you could render the points onto some pixel grid, and then do some kind of morphological operation, like `imclose`, and finish with Hough transform. Check out also this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/find-circle-in-noisy-data/5943#5943).

Comment: I tried thinking about this problem in terms of a convex hull, but I thought: what if I am given a sphere of data points? Or a pseudo-random set of data? Would the convhull function still work?

Comment: I think a convex hull approach disables the ability to choose on how much points you want to base your fit resulting in a fit with limited accuracy.

Comment: @EJG89, yes, it should be a pre-processing step to remove points inside the triangle.

Comment: The convex hull in your example would consist of 4 points (on the top left side) while the whole purpose of making a fit is to adjust for variation. By selecting only the convex hull points the polyfit will always be an overestimate.

Comment: @EJG89, you should select points that are close enough to the hull, not only those who are on it.

Comment: The problem is in 'close enough'. Some while ago I struggles with vicinity searches (point particle clouds) and these get computationally expensive very quickly. Thinking of it polyfit might actually be an efficient and effective option for this problem.